# Bing Image search v7 not working on React Native

Tags: azure, react-native, bing-api

I am trying to use the below code, however, getting the error -"Request failed with status code 401"

```
  const fetchImages = async () => {
    const arr = [
      {
        Product: 'Refrigerator',
      },
      {
        Product: 'Washing Machine',
      },
    ];
    try {
      const apiKey = 'MY_KEY';

      const baseUrl = 'https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search';

      const images = [];

      for (const item of arr) {
        const query = encodeURIComponent(item.Product);
        const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}?q=${query}`, {
          headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': apiKey,
          },
        });
        console.log('Bing response', response);

        if (response.data?.value?.[0]?.thumbnailUrl) {
          images.push(response.data.value[0].thumbnailUrl);
        }
      }
      console.log('images', images);

      setImageData(images);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
    }
  };
```

When checked the caught error, below is what I found, but I checked the API_key multiple times and even though I am using the correct API_KEY, the problem still remains.

```
{\"code\": \"Invalid authorization credentials.\"}, {\"code\": \"InvalidAuthorization\", \"subCode\": \"AuthorizationRedundancy\", \"message\": \"Only one authorization method can be used at a time.\", \"moreDetails\": \"Multiple authorization methods.\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're receiving indicates an issue with the authorization credentials. Specifically, the error "Only one authorization method can be used at a time." suggests that there might be multiple authorization methods being used.

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

1. Check the API Key: Ensure that the API key you're using is correct
   and has the necessary permissions for the Bing Image Search API.
2. Headers: Ensure that you're only setting the
   'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' header for authorization and not using
   any other headers that might be related to authorization.
3. Axios Global Configuration: If you have any global configurations
   set for Axios (like default headers), ensure that they aren't
   conflicting with the headers you're setting in this request. For
   instance, if you have a default Authorization header set globally,
   it might conflict with the Bing API header.
4. Endpoint URL: Ensure that the endpoint URL is correct. The base URL
   you provided seems correct, but it's always a good idea to
   double-check against the official documentation.
5. Re-generate API Key: Sometimes, the API key might have issues. Try
   regenerating a new API key from the Azure portal and use that in
   your code.
6. Network Proxies: If you're behind a corporate network or using a
   VPN, sometimes they can interfere with requests. Try running the
   code outside of such networks.
7. Use Postman or another API testing tool: Before integrating it into
   your React Native code, test the endpoint with tools like Postman to
   ensure that the API key and endpoint are working as expected.
8. Check for Extra Headers: If you're using any middleware or
   interceptors with Axios, ensure they aren't adding any additional
   headers to the request.

If after trying the above steps you're still facing the issue, consider reaching out to Microsoft support or checking the Azure portal for any additional insights or logs related to your API requests.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT